# How do we know that a surface integral is the same as an iterated double integral?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm going through my professor's calculus notes for integration of a function $f(x,y)$ over a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It defines partitions of a rectangle $R$ into subrectangles, and then says that the integral of $f(x,y)$ is the supremum of the lower sum (or infimum of upper sum) defined here :

[image: definition of lower and upper sums]

So in essence the integral of $f(x,y)$ over $R$ : $$\int^{}_{R} f\,dV$$ is the sum of the volume of these infinitesimal rectangles, he posts another picture to illustrate :

[image]

---

Here's my question : I know that the volume underneath the surface described by $f(x,y)$ is computed as an iterated double integral : $\int_{c}^{d} \left(\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) \,dx\right)\,dy$,     (where the rectangle $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is described as $R = [a,b] \times [c,d]$). However from my understanding, what the iterated double integral does is calculate the area underneath an '$x$-slice' as a function of $y$ ( as $F(y) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) \,dx$  ) , and then sums up all these areas as $\int_{c}^{d} F(y) \,dy$ . Professor provides animation here for [reference](https://www.math3d.org/AYh5Eb7sB).

This is not the same as measuring the volume underneath every infinitesmal subrectangle, and adding them up. If we were talking about the volume of a cheese, the above partition integral definition $\int_{R} f\,dV$ amounts to slicing the cheese into a bunch of rectangles along $x$ and $y$, then measuring the volume of each and adding them.
What an iterated double integral does as I've described it, would be to simply slice the cheese into a bunch of slices along $x$ only, measure the volume of those, and add them together. My question is how do I rigorously know these operations are equivalent?

In short, why is the following true? : $$\int_{R} f\,dV = \int_{c}^{d} \left(\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) \, dx\right) \, dy $$

And why is $dV = dxdy$ ?

Comment: Could you give me a name or link of such a theorem? I looked more through my book and found something called Fubini's theorem, however I'm unsure if Fubini's theorem alone suffices to answer my question. 

And to your second point, I put differential forms because of the last line where I ask why is $dV = dxdy$, I searched a bit and found things related to differential forms, however they are above my head.

Comment: See Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds text, page 59 for the proof. The proof is relatively short, and you already seem to have understood the main idea behind the proof; the rest is a matter of transcribing this carefully into supremum, infimum and using the correct inequalities. You just have to be slightly careful when dealing with Riemann/Darboux integrals, as you are right now, to ensure that things are well-defined (though when $f$ is continuous these issues disappear...though you of course still need to prove that). Anyway, just read that tiny section of Spivak, everything's there.

Comment: @peek-a-boo , thank you for the recommendation, funny enough I have already picked it up and will be going through it when I have the time coming up. I suppose since this is all self study as my course has ended (although I didn't do too well, I'm attempting to fix that), I wanted some confirmation on my line of thinking from here. It's why my post is so lengthy and detailed in regards to how I think the integrals work.